# Is it possible to make Windows 10 show symbolic links with a different icon in Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link, junction

I would like to know when I am browsing a symbolic link folder as I have had issues with copying directories then missing the fact that symbolic links have been lost through the copy operation etc. Is there a way to visualise symbolic links in Explorer?

Answer (score 8):

Natively, no, there does not appear to be a way to do it.

But you can with an Explorer shell extension, such as [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).

Comment: +1 for Link Shell Extension. It's an amazing little program.

Comment: Note that you might have to do some registry hacking to get the icons to show up, such as prepending empty spaces before registry names: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#faq

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the bad answer before.

You can either right click the symbolic link (this may have not been an option in previous versions of windows) and open Properties > Customize > Change Icon...

or

Create a desktop.ini file in the folder the symbolic link opens and add in the following:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll,137
```

You can get the number doing the first option on a local folder and copying it's desktop.ini. Got the info from here: https://superuser.com/a/687031/986631

<strike>I know this post is old but here is a solution I found. Their may be an easier/better way but it has worked for me. You will need to change the CreateShortcut, TargetPath, and IconLocation. Icon numbers start with 0 and count going from top to bottom. It may not show the icon right away but you will be able to at least change it once created.</strike>

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$Favorite = $Shell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\$env:username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network` Shortcuts\Test.lnk")
$Favorite.TargetPath = "\\server\directory";
$Favorite.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,8"
$Favorite.Save()
```

Comment: This doesn't create a symbolic link, it creates a shortcut.