# Why can't I set 'attrib +h +s' on Desktop.ini on network drive

Tags: windows-10, network-drive, attributes, desktop.ini

I'm trying to use custom icons for folders on a network drive and I've followed all the usual advice but cannot set the right attributes on the desktop.ini file. I'm using Windows 10 and have so far...

1) Tried the usual desktop tools for changing some attributes through properties settings

2) Tried to set +h +s manually from an elevated command prompt

3) Set my permissions on desktop.ini to Full Control

Oddly, when I set the attributes at the command prompt it returns without error, but when I list again with 'attrib' nothing has changed. I can't even get the file to hide using the GUI desktop tools!

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What OS is the network share using? If its on a NAS, then it uses linux. Linux does not understand the +h attribute and requires you to rename the file or folder starting with a . to set that property.

Comment: That's not wrong, but... not all NASes run Linux, and running Linux **does not imply** that the server won't understand DOS attributes. Samba (the Linux SMB server) has had the ability to store them in several different ways (xattrs, database, Unix bits) for probably over a decade. It's just that the particular NAS firmware has disabled all of those options.

Comment: [How can I make desktop.ini work on network locations?](https://superuser.com/questions/149728/how-can-i-make-desktop-ini-work-on-network-locations)