# desktop.ini in network folders problems

Tags: icons, desktop.ini

I am testing `desktop.ini` on network folders and have a problem.

**Shared from a windows server**, when creating a local folder with icon and copying it to the network location, the icon is saved, if I copy or rename it again, the icon is saved. But if I create a new folder and copy the `desktop.ini` from the old one, the icon does not appear. The folders have the same permissions and the same attributes.

From **linux with samba**, when copying from local to network, the icon is saved but when copying or renaming it is lost and it does not work if I copy the `desktop.ini`

I don't understand why when copying `desktop.ini` to a network folder created by me it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make desktop.ini work on network locations?](https://superuser.com/questions/149728/how-can-i-make-desktop-ini-work-on-network-locations)

Comment: I had already seen it but its solution does not work, you can try it on windows, create a folder and create your desktop.ini and try what it says but it does not work. There is something hidden in the permissions or something else that makes it not work.

Comment: You should perhaps read again all the answers in that post.

Comment: We don't expect necessarily that the accepted answer on the marked duplicate answers your question so much that at least one of the answers does, indicating the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

is the read-only file attribute

check folder with:

```
attrib folderName
```

if they don't have R set +r:

```
attrib +r forlderName
```