# Network folder icons disappeared - What could be the cause?

Tags: windows-10, networking, nas, samba, icons

We had been using folder icons on our (QNAP) NAS to simplify which projects are done and which need some attention. Somehow since a week or so, the icons don't appear anymore. I started investigating with the hints from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/149728/how-can-i-make-desktop-ini-work-on-network-locations/1085558?newreg=1326b301166c4ea8b7263be89ad84a9d).

So far I checked:

- the samba-config, which seems to be fine (i connected by SSH to the NAS and checked for `store dos attributes = yes`)

  - maybe there is another method to check if the config is actually in use?
- the hidden and system files desktop.ini & the icon, which are fine as well (by `Get-ChildItem -Force | select Name, FullName, Attributes` in the Powershell)
- the readonly state of the folder, which is fine too (as above)

I'm running out of options. What else could I check to find out what has changed? Maybe it was an Windows Update? Or maybe an Update of the NAS? Or maybe something completely else...

Comment: This happened for me also around the same date, out of the blue (maybe some Windows update?). @rampage's answer below works.

Answer (score 3):

Create the following entry in registry
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]
"EnableShellShortcutIconRemotePath"=dword:00000001

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: At least in Windows 11 you need to reboot before this will work. Drove me crazy beore I found out.